# How can I emulate Google Cloud IoT Core?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python, emulation, emulator

I am working with several GCP products and I want to emulate the behaviour of my future application.
I am working with Python/Django.
I already emulate Google Pub/Sub and Google Cloud Functions.
Both of these functionalities are working fine and communicate together.

Yet, I would need to add a 'Google Cloud IoT Core' emulator. This way I could send event registrations to Pub/Sub or modify data from IoTCore devices (such as messages for instance).

I already searched and did not find my happy place...
Is there any way to simulate this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this [open source Google IoT Core emulator](https://firedome.io/blog/wish-google-cloud-iot-core-had-an-emulator-weve-got-you-covered/) from firedome.io that implements four main features of Core IoT:

- MQTT bridge capabilities
- Creating new registries
- Provisioning new devices
- Transmitting telemetry data into Pub/Sub

I suspect that you found it, but there is a typo in the link so here is the [repository](https://github.com/firedome/iot-core-emulator)

Comment: Oh thank you yes I had a problem with the link !!

Comment: Here's ours https://mqttlab.iotsim.io/gcp .